# Add Custom Callbacks to Asyncio.Protocol Python

Tags: python, callback, protocols, python-asyncio

I wonder how i can add my own callbacks to the asyncio's class Protocol.
For example here is my client class:

```
class EchoClientProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def data_received(self, data):
        print('Data received: {!r}'.format(data.decode()))
```

I would like to add this callback:

```
def hello_received(self):
    print("Hello received")
```

which will be called when  "Hello" is received.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You should parse incoming data in `data_received()` and after reaching *hello* may call your own callback like `hello_received()`

Comment: Yes it's an option but how do i manage hundreds of different messages ? The client is connected to a game server which sends packets defined by an id. So i want to callback the receipt of packet of id "x".